# Error: Invalid format passed to crm.formatmoney

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

A donor provided the following screenshot.  Based on what we can tell, the donor's credit card was declined - but I am not sure how they got this error - which led the donor to thinking our systems were the problem. Has anyone experienced this before?
Latest Drupal 7 and Civi. Using webform, omnipay, cybersource.

[image]

Comment: What version of CiviCRM and Webform CiviCRM module do you have on this site?

Comment: At the time 5.18.x and latest webform.

Comment: Did you ever find out the problem? I'm having the same problem now on Wordpress 5.4, Civi 5.24.6.

Comment: kapn - did you figure out this problem? we are now seeing this on a WP site which changed to using shortcodes

Comment: No idea - it never came up again.